# react native expo run-ios

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

Im getting this error while trying to do expo build:ios
this is the error I'm getting:

```
[15:38:20] Error while gathering & validating credentials
[15:38:20] Reason: Unexpected response, raw: {
  "responseId": "ee62c44e-db97-4c81-80ad-705b98416466",
  "resultCode": 7460,
  "resultString": "Maximum number of certificates generated",
  "userString": "You already have a current iOS Distribution certificate or a pending certificate request.",
  "creationTimestamp": "2018-11-18T13:38:20Z",
  "protocolVersion": "QH65B2",
  "userLocale": "en_US",
  "requestUrl": "https://developer.apple.com/services-account/QH65B2/account/ios/certificate/submitCertificateRequest.action",
  "httpCode": 200
}



IM USING EXPO:
No currently active or previous builds for this project.
? How would you like to upload your credentials?
 Expo handles all credentials, you can still provide overrides

We need your Apple ID/password to manage certificates and
provisioning profiles from your Apple Developer account.

Note: Expo does not keep your Apple ID or your Apple password.

? What's your Apple ID?(**valid account- I'm getting into my account while trying to do it**)
? Password? [hidden]
[15:38:04] Validating Credentials...
[15:38:09] Only 1 team associated with your account, using Team ID: MD8BX56B88
? Will you provide your own Distribution Certificate? Let Expo handle the process
? Will you provide your own Push Certificate? Let Expo handle the process
```

what have I done wrong?
I can't find any info' online

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to developer.apple.com and delete the certificates that have been generated for this bundleIdentifier previously. If that doesn't work by itself, you can also change the bundleIdentifier name and try again.